# How do I send a message to myself with PowerAutomate?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I am developing a PowerAutomate flow,

I want to use the function "post message in chat or channel",
I can send messages to anyone in "one to one" private chats but not on the private chat i have with myself.

Has somebody found a way to message himself via power automate?

I can't create it as a "new chat" in PA because it says users cannot be duplicate.

Then i figured out i had to find the ID of the chat with myself.
I tried using the microsoft graph api to retrieve the id from "me/chats" but the chat with myself is not shown.
I tried many different filters and expansions with no success.

I also tried analyzing the id itself and discovered that, in the case of "one to one" chats, it's made of {the sender id} and {the receiver id}

I then tried constructing an id that contains 19:{myuserid}_{myuserid}@{domain} but it responds that there is no record.

I tried many combinations,
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible using Power Automate.

I opened Teams in the browser and opened the existing chat with myself and grabbed the URL

https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/48:notes?ctx=chat

Other chats were similar, so I copied the `48:notes` and used that as the Conversation Id. I also tried it with a different account and the Id was the same.

You need to use the "Post message in a chat or channel"

- Post as: User
- Post in: Group chat
- Group chat: Enter custom value `48:notes`

[image: Screenshot of Power Automate flow]

And here is a short demo of it in action:

[image: GIF of Power Automate flow running and posting message to Teams]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround for this problem.

Make a group chat with some coworkers, then have them all leave. Now that you're by yourself in the group chat, you can automate post message to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to send messages/cards to self chat as the self-chat id is not exposed.You can raise suggest this feature at [Microsoft Teams Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Please not that if you post card using below settings it will send a card to you but as a separate chat with Power Automate. [image]

[image]