# How to search for keywords in your own personal chat

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

Trying to use the following trigger in PowerAutomate: "When keywords are mentioned" to look for a keyword in my personal Teams channel, but it doesnt seem to pick up the keyword.

Sending messages to myself via "post message to chat" with the same conversation ID does work
[How do I send a message to myself with PowerAutomate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315375/how-do-i-send-a-message-to-myself-with-powerautomate/75320541#75320541)

I tried configured the step using the same message type and conversation ID settings that work with other steps

Comment: Are you trying to use trigger condition as 'When keywords are mentioned' in self/personal chat? In power automate, the message type for this trigger are only 'Channel' and 'Group chat'. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCYy7.png

Comment: Correct, the "Group chat" message type with the manually entered conversation id '48:notes' works to post chat messages to you self/personal chat. So I don't understand why the same setting does not work for the "when keywords are mentioned" trigger.

Comment: Using '48:notes' as conversation id for self chat is not recommended or officially documented anywhere. self-chat id is not exposed. So in order to use this trigger, you need to either enter any group chat conversation id or channel id.

Comment: The self chat id is exposed on the web interface of Teams :)

Comment: Though it is exposed on web interface, its not suggested/officially documented.